# Down-cast ComponentRegistration to non-generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, castle-windsor

I`m using Castle.Windsor library, and what i want is to get "Implementation" property, from all items in IRegistration[].

I have following interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IA
  {
    int a { get; set; }
  }

  public class A : IA
  {
    public int a { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IB
  {
    int b { get; set; }
  }

  public class B : IB
  {
    public int b { get; set; }
  }
```

And a static class which contains this Components:

```
  public static class Bootekstraperek
  {
    private static readonly IRegistration[] _commonRegistrations =
    {
      Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<A>(),
      Component.For<IB>().ImplementedBy<B>()
    };

    public static void Test()
    {
      List<IRegistration> list = _commonRegistrations.ToList();

      foreach (var registration in list)
      {
        ComponentRegistration a = registration as ComponentRegistration;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Implementation.FullName);
      }
    }
  }
```

And of course variable a is null after every iteration.
It works only when i cast to Generic ComponentRegistration

```
var a = registration as ComponentRegistration<A>;
```

But, that dont helps me if i have too much different components inside this array. So Switch statement is not an option. 
I have tried using reflections, but i still didn`t managed to properly cast.

How can i achieve what i want With or Without using reflections?

thxia.

Comment: I'm guessing the actual problem you're trying to solve isn't just to write all registrations to the console? If not, can you share what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve? There may be different approaches possible.

Comment: I need to export all "Implementation" properties from this components. And that shoud be done in non-hardcode way

Answer (score 2):

This is not easy because the `IRegistration` API was never meant to be used in this way.

So my answer has two parts.

1. How you can do it. Use `dynamic`.

you only need to change a small bit of your code:

```
foreach (dynamic registration in list)
{
  Console.WriteLine(registration.Implementation.FullName);
}
```

2. What is the underlying goal you're trying to achieve here? Have a look at Windsor's diagnostics if your goal is to keep a level of visibility into what gets registered, how and be on a lookout for potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

A small amount of Reflection solves the problem (it is a small amount, but it looks verbose, because Reflection):

```
foreach (var registration in list)
{
  Console.WriteLine(
         ((Type)registration.GetType().GetProperty(
                "Implementation"
         ).GetGetMethod().Invoke(
                registration,new object[] { })
         ).FullName);
}
```

Since you won't know the types that are being used as generic type parameters until runtime, I don't think there's a way to do this without any Reflection.

---

The above assumes that all of the registrations *will* be `ComponentRegistration<T>` objects of some sort. If that's an unsafe assumption, there may be some other implementations of `IRegistration` that don't implement an `Implementation` property or it may not be publicly accessible - so insert appropriate interim error checking if that's the case.